# Javascript function not called from php

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I am working on a website wherein I am using php to retrieve some entries from the database and am displaying them on screen. Now, i want to pass one of the columns, which is an address, to a javascript function.

The function will take in the variable and plot it on the map. I am using the Google maps geocoding which takes in an address string and plots it.I need to call the function from php by passing a variable to it.

I am not able to achieve the end result. In fact the javascript function isn't getting called at all. I am attaching the javascript function and the php code which calls the java script function. I am stuck here since quite some time now and am anxiously waiting for a solution

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function map_function(addr){
    alert("function called with" + addr);

    // Define the addresses we want to map.
    var clubs = addr;
    // Create a new Geocoder
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    // Locate the address using the Geocoder.
    geocoder.geocode( { "address": clubs }, function(results, status) {

        // If the Geocoding was successful
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            // Create a Google Map at the latitude/longitude returned by the Geocoder.
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            // Add a marker at the address.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

        } else {
                try {
                    console.error("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                } catch(e) {}
            }
    });
}
}
</script>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $addr = $row['ADDRESS'];
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">map_function({$addr});</script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">map_function("{$addr}");</script>';
```

And move the map_function outside the document ready handler.

Comment: still not working. The alert is not getting displayed. Which would mean that the function is still not getting called. :(

Comment: Could you move the function map_function outside document ready handler?

Comment: Yes, that solved it. Thank you. But now, the map is plotting only one element at a time. It is not saving the previous plotting. Do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: You are redrawing the map everytime: var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

Move this code to a new function and call it once.

Comment: Yes yes I saw that right now. I'll make it static. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are trying to call is in a closure : the DOM ready handler

It is not possible to access it from outside.

Get ride of the DOM ready handler. If you need the DOM to be ready, wrap the caller instead on the called.

```
$(function(){
    map_function("{$addr}")
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :) But now, the map is plotting only one element at a time. It is not saving the previous plotting. Do you have any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use curly-braces and put the code inside onready function.

and last put all php code inside script tag. Like:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

echo '$(document).ready(function(e) {';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $addr = $row['ADDRESS'];
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">map_function(\''.$addr.'\');</script>';
}
echo '});';
?>
</script>
```

Hope this will help you... :)